# Unescaping / decoding an email address set in a cookie

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encoding

I've stored an email address in a cookie, and I'm sending it to a jsp file on google appengine to be verified.  The `@` is coming through as `%40`.  I need to get it back to an `@`, and convert any other special chars that might have been encoded.  Are there classes available through appengine that deal with this conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at URLDecoder and URLEncoder:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Looking at the [JRE whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) they are both fine to use.